# Python unit test ignoring mocked response

Tags: python, mocking, patch

I'm trying to make a simple mock for a custom function in python. This function calls out to aws, and returns a list of ip addresses for all instances in an environment. Since I'm writing unit tests, I want to be able to mock the response from that function so I don't need to hit AWS in order to test.

The issue I think, comes from the target I'm using. I've tried everything I can thing of but haven't had any luck.

I've tried using patch this way:

```
def test_mock_ip_response(self):
    with patch("app.api.commands.ip_addresses", return_value=["10.10.10.10"]):
    results=ip_addresses("stage")
    print (results)
    assert False
```

and with a decorator:

```
@patch("app.api.commands.ip_addresses")
def test_mock_bash_response(self, mock_ip_addresses):
    mock_ip_addresses.return_value=["10.10.10.10"]
    results=ip_addresses("stage")
    print (results)
    assert False
```

Either way, the function ip_addresses always tried to call out to AWS, so the call isn' getting caught.

Oh and I know the asserts are set to false, that's just so pytest will show me the stdout for my testing.

Update:
Including the code for ip_addresses:

```
def ip_addresses(environment: str) -> List[str]:
    client = get_client("ec2")

    filters = #removed since they contain naming conventions
    response = client.describe_instances(Filters=filters)

    return [
        i["PrivateIpAddress"] for r in response["Reservations"] for i in r["Instances"]
    ]
```

Comment: Show us the code you are testing.

Comment: Maybe an issue with importing the value before patching? Is there any change if you import after the `patch`, or maybe just import the module and not the value directly. ie `results=app.api.commands.ip_addresses("stage")`

Comment: I cleaned it up and updated the post. Thanks!

Comment: I see the problem now: you have to patch where you are using the function, here it is your test module: `@patch(ip_addresses)`. But what are you testing then? The mock?

Comment: @flakes I tried calling it with the whole path and no luck. Just an undefined error.
And moving the import to after the `patch` just causes it to fail. `patch` should be looking for the memory location of an existing path and redirecting it, so it has to already be called before you can call `patch`

Comment: @KlausD. I'm planning to test a function that calls ip_addresses but I need to be able to mock out that call so I can prevent it from trying to call aws when we test.

Comment: Have you used the full path of your unittests in mock.patch decorator?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working so I'll make sure to post the answer here. It has to do with how I was calling `ip_addresses` inside my test function.

Instead of calling

`results=ip_addresses`

I just needed change that to:

`results=commands.ip_addresses`